# Integrate @polkadot/api with Vuexy React Template

Tags: polkadot-js, substrate-front-end

I try to use PolkadotJs with my website create with Vuexy React but i have this error:
./node_modules/@polkadot/api/packageInfo.js 6:14
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (6:14)
File was processed with these loaders:

- ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
  You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
  | export const packageInfo = {
  |   name: '@polkadot/api',

> path: import.meta && import.meta.url ? new URL(import.meta.url).pathname.substring(0, new URL(import.meta.url).pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) : 'auto',
> |   type: 'esm',
> |   version: '9.1.1'

This is my package.json

```
  "name": "vuexy-react-admin-dashboard",
  "version": "8.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@casl/ability": "^5.4.3",
    "@casl/react": "^2.3.0",
    "@craco/craco": "^6.4.3",
    "@fullcalendar/core": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/interaction": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/list": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/react": "^5.11.1",
    "@fullcalendar/timegrid": "^5.11.0",
    "@fullcalendar/timeline": "^5.11.0",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^2.8.10",
    "@polkadot/api": "^9.1.1",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.3",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.2.5",
    "animate.css": "4.1.1",
    "apexcharts": "^3.35.2",
    "apexcharts-clevision": "^3.28.5",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "^1.20.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.1.0",
    "bs-stepper": "1.7.0",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "cleave.js": "1.6.0",
    "draft-js": "0.11.7",
    "draftjs-to-html": "0.9.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.5",
    "flatpickr": "^4.6.13",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "html-to-draftjs": "1.5.0",
    "i18next": "^21.8.2",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.4",
    "i18next-xhr-backend": "3.2.2",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.5.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "nouislider": "^15.5.0",
    "nouislider-react": "^3.4.1",
    "postcss-rtl": "^1.5.0",
    "prismjs": "^1.28.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "rc-input-number": "^7.3.4",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.1.0",
    "react-contexify": "5.0.0",
    "react-copy-to-clipboard": "^5.1.0",
    "react-country-flag": "^3.0.2",
    "react-data-table-component": "^7.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-draft-wysiwyg": "^1.14.7",
    "react-dropzone": "^14.2.1",
    "react-feather": "~2.0.3",
    "react-flatpickr": "^3.10.12",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.31.1",
    "react-hot-toast": "2.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.16.9",
    "react-paginate": "^8.1.3",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-player": "^2.10.1",
    "react-rating": "2.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.2",
    "react-select": "^5.3.2",
    "react-shepherd": "3.3.6",
    "react-slidedown": "^2.4.7",
    "react-sortablejs": "6.0.0",
    "reactstrap": "9.0.1",
    "recharts": "^2.1.9",
    "redux": "^4.2.0",
    "redux-debounced": "0.5.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.1",
    "sass": "^1.51.0",
    "screenfull": "5.0.2",
    "sortablejs": "^1.12.0",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.4.14",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^5.0.0",
    "swiper": "^8.1.5",
    "wnumb": "1.2.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "yarn": "^1.22.18",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.js\"",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.js src/**/*.js",
    "lint:fix": "eslint src/**/*.js --fix"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/sortablejs": "^1.10.6",
    "eslint": "^8.15.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.29.4",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^12.6.0"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "react-error-overlay": "6.0.9",
    "react-scripts/postcss-preset-env/postcss-custom-properties": "^10.0.0"
  },
  "homepage": ""
}
```

craco.config.js

```
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  reactScriptsVersion: 'react-scripts',
  style: {
    sass: {
      loaderOptions: {
        sassOptions: {
          includePaths: ['node_modules', 'src/assets']
        }
      }
    },
    postcss: {
      plugins: [require('postcss-rtl')()]
    }
  },
  babel: {
    plugins: [["@babel/plugin-proposal-private-methods", { "loose": true }]]
  },
  webpack: {
    alias: {
      '@src': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
      '@assets': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@core/assets'),
      '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@core/components'),
      '@layouts': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@core/layouts'),
      '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/redux'),
      '@styles': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/@core/scss'),
      '@configs': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/configs'),
      '@utils': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utility/Utils'),
      '@hooks': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utility/hooks')
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not familiar with Vuexy and/or craco, but from the above error it would seem that it is using Webpack 4 as a bundler. WP 4 does not have support for import.meta.url it is only available on WP 5.

If there is no current version of Vuexy/craco available that are using WP 5, you would need to add additional loaders to your config.

Support for this can be added by a 3rd party loader as [described in the js api build FAQ](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/usage/FAQ#on-webpack-4-i-have-a-parse-error-on-importmetaurl)

Comment: with yarn update, working.... but now i have another errore :(

Comment: ./node_modules/@polkadot/api-derive/type/HeaderExtended.js Module not found: Can't resolve '.........../node_modules/babel-preset-react-app/node_modules/@babel/runtime/helpers/esm/classPrivateFieldLooseBase.js' in '.....\node_modules\@polkadot\api-derive\type'

Comment: The above comment points to your specific babel config, i.e. babel-preset-react-app applies the helpers. Ensure that, when passing "loose", you pass it everywhere. So above you pass it to private methods, it is most probably required for class properties as well.